# Make use of node binary in android

Tags: java, android, node.js, binaries

I have managed to get a binary for node 7.2 and I would like to use it to call a node module from an application in Java. Is there a way of achieving this? On Windows it's fairly straightwordward, you ship the binary and call it from within your application, but how do I do that on android with Java? is that even possible?

please excuse the noobish question, I'm quite new to android development.

Comment: Is it possible: probably yes, is it wise: probably no. What's the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a cordova app and I need to use a node backend, but webhooks don't seem to work, so what I was going to do was write a plugin that executes this node binary which executes a custom HTTP server so that I can use this node module

Comment: You're right, it's probably not the most glamourous or the most efficient or in any way a good idea, but it seems to me to be the only possible solution. Please correct me if I'm wrong